# How to Set/Get Images (BLOB) using the ResultSet

Tags: java, image, jdbc, blob

I am having a hard-time trying to just display images. I'm using a JLabel to display the image. I'm using `resultset.getBytes("Images")` to retrieve the images from the database, the problem arises when I *try* to display the images(s). The `setIcon` method doesn't work.

This is the method which I use to retrieve information and the images from the database:

```
public List<Employee> selectAllEmployees(){

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * from employees" );

        List testEmps = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        while ( resultset.next() ) {

            Employee e1 = new Employee(
                    resultset.getBytes("Images"));

            testEmps.add(e1);   

        }

        return testEmps;

    } catch ( Exception e1) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Please note - I have removed most of the code for ease. I do have connection to the database and have retrieved all other data. Just for pure convenience I have deleted most of the code.

This is the code I use to set all other data -

```
public void showEmps(int index){
    idTextField.setText(selectAllEmployees().get(index).getid());

    photoLabel.setIcon(selectAllEmployees().get(index).getImages());
}
```

I have left the `idTextField` just for demonstration purposes. And everything works as expected.

I know it's something to do with my Employee Class -

```
public class Employee extends Person {
    private String id;
    private String salary;
    private String startDate;
    private String title;
    private String email;
    private static byte [] Images;

    public Employee(){
        this("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", Images);
    }

    public Employee(String id, String Name, String Sex,  String date,  String address, String postcode, String natIncsNumber,
            String title, String startDate, String salary, String email, byte[] images){

        super(Name, Sex,natIncsNumber, date, address, postcode);
        this.id = id;

        this.startDate = date;
        this.title = title;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.email = email;
        Images = images;
    }
```

My question is, how do I solve the problem as in my Employee Class the images is of type `Bytes` I can use the `getBytes` statement to retrieve the images but there is no `setBytes` only set icon. I do have another code just to cycle through every single employee and this does show the images, however, it's using the `setIcon` method and using the `ImageIcon` method like so:

```
byte[] img = rs.getBytes("Images");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img);
Image im = image.getImage();
Image myImg = im.getScaledInstance(200, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon newImage = new ImageIcon(myImg);
```

Could someone please possibly help me out?

Comment: You have working code for the same problem. Why don't you use similar code for the first place?

Comment: @vanje As the resultSet returns the last record in the database, this method shows each record every-time the next button is selected.

Comment: But it doesn't matter whether you're treating the last record or the next record. What is the structural difference? You have a record and you want to show the image. You can make a method for that and call it in both cases.

Comment: @vanje So you're telling me I should make a separate method for byte[img]? However, due to the fact I'm using a super-class I get errors as the constructor is expecting another resultSet to get some data from the database. Could you possibly help me out? This is the very last piece of the puzzle for me.

Comment: Ok, maybe forget the method for now and concentrate on the steps you should follow. You have one piece of code where you read a record out of a result set, get the image bytes and use the `ImageIcon` class to show the image. Then go to the other piece of code where you read a record out of a result set and get the image bytes. Now you should do the same thing as in the first code section. Use the bytes to create the `ImageIcon` instance and show the image.

Comment: Ohh! I know how what you mean, however, I cannot for some reason use  byte[] img = resultset.getBytes("Images)" as tried it I just get an error.

Comment: Additionally you should look at your `Employee` class. The static member `Images` is confusing. Why static? And every constructor call overwrites it? So in the end you only have one set of images. And by convention field names should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove the static. And see how I can do it. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Same again. You have working code to read the image bytes out of the database and show the image. Do the same at the other place. What else do you want besides a working piece of code, working with the same data? You only have to transfer and adapt the code from one place to another. This should be fairly easy.

Comment: I tried, however I only get the first/last image. The do not change accordingly. I re-called `resultset.getBytes` and use  `byte[] img` and then added it to `testEmps.add(img);` this only gave me the third image. The issue isn't getting the image it's more to do with displaying it using  `photoLabel.setIcon(selectAllEmployees().get(index).getImages());`

Comment: And that is because `Images` is a static field instead of an instance field.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I remove Static I get an error and the option is to add the keyword static

Comment: Then probably something else in your code (for example the getter or setter) is also static, or depends on the current static-ness of the field. Fix that problem instead.